# Flask React App not Hot Reloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use Python Flask with a React Frontend. Here is my webpack file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    "./js/app.jsx",
    "./scss/main.scss"
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/static',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      { // sass / scss loader for webpack
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ // define where to save the file
      filename: '[name].bundle.css',
      allChunks: true,

    })  
  ]
};
```

I am not sure if this file is the problem, but for some reason, my app is not hot-reloading. Here is a simple repo that I setup for which hot reloading does not work: https://github.com/rishub/Flask_React

I am using 
webpack version: 3.8.1,
node version: 6.11.5, 
npm version: 3.10.10

I cannot seem to figure out why it is not reloading.
I run python app.py in one terminal and webpack --watch in the other.

The terminal with webpack seems to detect the changes to the React jsx files, however, the app does not reload on the browser unless I ***force*** refresh, even a regular refresh does not work.

If someone would be able to point out the problem or fork/make a PR to the repo, that would be great

Comment: Read the hot reloading docs carefully you need correct configuration according to correct webpack version

Comment: care to expand?

Answer (score 1):

With watch, you're only compiling the updates themselves & not interfacing with the application.

`--watch` is not a flag for hot reloading in your browser. It regulates registered files for changes and recompiles the Webpack output whenever there is a change within those files. However, it does not necessarily forward that output to the browser.

Your force refresh was syncing up with the new version served up by Webpack, and also disrupting the browser cache.

Hot Module Reloading needs to be done with some kind of additional tool like [Webpack HMR](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) and a configured Webpack Dev Server.

From the docs, Hot Reloading entails all of the following:

> The application asks the HMR runtime to check for updates.
>   The runtime asynchronously downloads the updates and notifies the application.
>   The application then asks the runtime to apply the updates.
>   The runtime synchronously applies the updates.

Comment: Also, since you're using flask as a backend, you will need to set up a proxy for your dev server in order to interface with backend content.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy